# Unable to get token from dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am using ESP8266 ESP-01 module, using FTDI to upload code using arduino IDE platform. I came accross dropbox manager library developed by lucasromeiro. 
I am herein providing github link for the library. https://github.com/lucasromeiro/DropboxManager/issues

I accepted the app in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=g0xkpmfu025pn8f suggested by developer, and obtained access code.
I didn't receive the token when myDrop.getToken("");

I did try the solution suggest by AAJAYS in the issue section(refer github link). I still don't receive the token. Thus I revereted back to version 2.4.2 in the boards -> ESP8266 -> version in arduino IDE and tried the code to obtain the token.

I did try contacting the dev and didn't hear back, What needs to be done to obtain token?

Comment: This seems to be a service provisioning issue, and nothing to do with programming. You should contact the developer directly. I vote to close this one as it has nothing to do programming.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help